# SQL Selecting Dates January to July if current date is less than or equal to July

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm pretty new with sql and programming in general, so I'm not sure of the syntax for this.  I have a table, and I want to select every row that occurs during a given school semester.  The turnover will be January 1st, and July 1st.  I want it to display all the entries for the current year, before July, or after july depending on the current month.  My Date column is in the sql date format.

Comment: Have you written any SQL at all? We would like you to show us what you tried, so we can help with that. As it stands, without table structure , example input and example output, it is not easy to help you.

Comment: What database you are using (Oracle, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: I am using mySQL.  Right now I am just selecting everything regardless of the year, SELECT * FROM `Lessons_Schedule` WHERE `Type`="ballroom"

Comment: I can do this in php a lot easier but I need to be able to pull the month and the year out.  I did  a little research and found the YEAR function.  Here's a little sample of what I'm trying to do.
SELECT * FROM `Lessons_Schedule` WHERE YEAR(`Date`)=YEAR(CURDATE())

From there I can work in my php into the query to do the same thing with month, but the syntax isn't working.  Like I said I've only been programming a little while, so this is all new.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @theUnicycleGuy Using `YEAR()` function on your date column makes it impossible for MySql to use index on that column if you have one (and you should since you filtering on that column) effectively forcing a full scan.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle you can use case statements in your where clause and take advantage of the fact that if you don't explicitly set a year on an Oracle date it assumes the current year.

```
select *
  from your_table
 where case
         when trunc(sysdate) > to_date('01-JUL', 'DD-MON') then
           to_date('01-JUL', 'DD-MON')
         else
           to_date('01-JAN', 'DD-MON')
       end < date_column;
```

I'll leave it to you to use make sure that you don't get first semester results if the current date is greater than the first of July.  One approach would be to employ a similar case statement, but I think there are cleaner ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

For MySql your query might look like

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE date BETWEEN CASE WHEN CURDATE() < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') 
                         THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01')
                         ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') END
                AND CASE WHEN CURDATE() < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') 
                         THEN LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-07-01'))
                         ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-12-31') END
```

it can also be rewritten as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN CURDATE() < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') 
              THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01')
              ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') END start_date,
         CASE WHEN CURDATE() < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-08-01') 
              THEN LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-07-01'))
              ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-12-31') END end_date
) q
 WHERE date BETWEEN q.start_date AND q.end_date
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5be33/3)** demo (MySql)

Comment: @theUnicycleGuy Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: I copied it in and replaced the table name and column name with my own and no luck.  In the SQL terminal of php MyAdmin, it is highlighting in red all the time functions like CURDATE() and DATE_FORMAT().  I am probably in over my head with this stuff at this point.  This is my first project with SQL